# Is this function right? Call a function with closure (swift - iOS)

Tags: ios, json, swift, api, alamofire

### The Problem

I have to search a movie on the API and return on my table view the movies searched.

### Language

Swift 3 - xcode 8

### Function to get Json from API

```
func searchMoviesOnJson(imdbTitle: String, completionHandler: @escaping (Dictionary<String, Any>?) -> ()) {

let urlByName: String = "https://www.omdbapi.com/?s=\(imdbTitle)&type=movie"

//returns a list of movies that contains the title searched
//------------------------------------------------


Alamofire.request(urlByName).responseJSON {
    response in

    switch response.result {

    case .success(let value):
        let moviesJSON = value
        completionHandler(moviesJSON as? Dictionary<String, Any>)

    case .failure(_):
        completionHandler(nil)
    }
}
//------------------------------------------------
```

This class called Movie (that will be searched on the API):

```
class Movie {

var poster: String?
var title : String?
var year  : String?
var imdbID: String?


init(poster: String?, title: String?, year: String?, imdbID: String?) {

    if let isPoster = poster { self.poster = isPoster }
    else { self.poster = nil }

    if let isTitle = title { self.title = isTitle }
    else { self.title = nil }

    if let isYear = year { self.year = isYear }
    else { self.year = nil }

    if let isImdbID = imdbID { self.imdbID = isImdbID }
    else { self.imdbID = nil }

  }
}
```

And then, my DAO:

```
class MovieDAO {


//Search By Title

static func getMovies(imdbTitle: String, completionHandler: @escaping (([Movie]) -> ())) {

    searchMoviesOnJson(imdbTitle: imdbTitle, completionHandler: {
      newMoviesJSON in

        if let moviesJSON = newMoviesJSON {

            if moviesJSON["Error"] != nil { return }

            else {

                //casting
                let arrayOfMovies: [[String : String]] = newMoviesJSON!["Search"] as! [[String : String]]

                var fetchedMovies = [Movie]()

                for eachFetchedMovie: [String : String] in arrayOfMovies {

                    var poster: String?
                    var title : String?
                    var year  : String?
                    var imdbID: String?

                    if let isPoster = eachFetchedMovie["Poster"] { poster = isPoster }
                    else { poster = nil }

                    if let isTitle = eachFetchedMovie["Title"] { title = isTitle }
                    else { title = nil }

                    if let isYear = eachFetchedMovie["Year"] { year = isYear }
                    else { year = nil }

                    if let isImdbID = eachFetchedMovie["imdbID"] { imdbID = isImdbID }
                    else { imdbID = nil }

                    let movie: Movie = Movie(poster: poster, title: title, year: year, imdbID: imdbID)

                    fetchedMovies.append(movie)

                }
                completionHandler(fetchedMovies)
            }

        }

    })

  }
}
```

First of all, what is a closure and what would happen if I don't use it in this functions?

Now, how can I test this function? I call it in my AppDelegate like:

```
print(MovieDAO.getMovies(imdbTitle: "arq"))
```

But the xcode returns an error saying that is missing a parameter in the call. So, can you explain this to me? I read about it but I'm a beginner and it's still confusing to me.

Oh, I would like to print an array with the searched title. I'm almost sure that my function is not returning that. How can I adapt the function to do that?

Just for better comprehension, the API gives this Json for the movie searched:

```
{
Response = True;
Search =     (
            {
        Poster = "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjAxODQ2MzkyMV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNjU3MTE5OTE@._V1_SX300.jpg";
        Title = ARQ;
        Type = movie;
        Year = 2016;
        imdbID = tt5640450;
    },
            {
        Poster = "N/A";
        Title = Arq;
        Type = movie;
        Year = 2011;
        imdbID = tt2141601;
    },
            {
        Poster = "N/A";
        Title = "A.R.Q.";
        Type = movie;
        Year = 2015;
        imdbID = tt3829612;
    }
);
totalResults = 3;
}
```

### Update 1:

I did like the suggestion and called (on my AppDelegate, just for test and see if it getting what I want, in this case, a list of the movies that contains the "arq" on title) my function like this:

```
MovieDAO.getMovies(imdbTitle: "arq") {
        (movies: [Movie]) in
        // Do something with the movies
        print(movies)
    }
```

The return was this error:
[image: (lldb) error]

What is wrong with this line that is in green?

Comment: Shrink your code, only put main things

Comment: closure is  used for callback while we got response from server or any other same purpose .

Comment: what you want to do ?

Comment: @KKRocks I have a table view with a search bar. What I wanna do is: the user type a imdbTitle on search bar and my table view show the results according to the response the API gives me (like this JSON file). The table view would show the return of my getMovies function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Problem**

The function you are trying to call has a method signature like:

`getMovies(imdbTitle: String, completionHandler: @escaping (([Movie]) -> ()))`

You are trying to call it with just the first parameter: `imdbTitle`. The error you are seeing is because you never pass in the completion handler- you are missing the last parameter.

**The Solution**

Change your call to include the completion block, like so:

```
MovieDAO.getMovies(imdbTitle: "Title") {
  (movies: [Movie]) in
  // Do something with the movies
  print(movies)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I use this and the app crashed. (as you can see on the image on my question updated). Do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Think of a closure as a bunch of code that you want to run, that you save as a variable that you could then pass to a function.

That's what you are doing in your GetMovies function call inside MoviesDAO

```
static func getMovies(imdbTitle: String, completionHandler: @escaping (([Movie]) -> ())) {
```

The completionHandler parameter is expecting a block of code that takes an array of Movie objects and does something with it. (Probably printing in your case).

Because, what is happening is that you are asking some API (IMDB), "Hey, I want you to give me a bunch of movies with the name 'arg' in it". IMDB can't immediately give you that information and you don't want the rest of your program to wait around, so your GetMovies function call asks for some code to run after it gets the array of movie objects.

```
completionHandler(fetchedMovies)
```

You've named your function parameters a little confusingly as well which probably isn't helping what you're reading. You have some funky name clashing with the completionHandler of the SearchMoviesOnJSON function. So I'm going to rename your getMovies function but leave SearchMoviesOnJSON alone.

```
static func getMovies(imdbTitle: String, handlerForMovieArray: @escaping (([Movie]) -> ()))
```

So instead of calling

```
print(MovieDAO.getMovies(imdbTitle: "arq"))
```

What you should do is define a closure (a chunk of code) that the getMovies function calls at the end.

```
MovieDAO.getMovies(imdbTitle: "arg", handlerForMovieArray: {
    MoviesList in //<-- This is your input. 
    //Your array of movies that is being passed by the call to "handlerForMovieArray"

    //Do some fancy code stuff here. Probably want to loop over MoviesList and print the values you want
})
```

I hope this helps! Reach out if you have more questions.

Comment: Great explanation, thanks. I did this : MovieDAO.getMovies(imdbTitle: "arq") {
            (movies: [Movie]) in
            // Do something with the movies
            print(movies)
        }

but the app crash when I run. Returning only a (lldb) on console.What does this mean? On my MovieDAO it's green in one line (see the image updated in my question).

Comment: I have no ideia. Like I said, I'm a newbie and did this following a bunch of tutorials, I though it was right but I guess is not. The xcode turn this line green (as you can see in the image) but I don't know why, the console only said "(lldb)".

Comment: It looks like you are debugging the code there. Have you run the code without the breakpoints you added?

Comment: Yes, without call the function to print movies, the app/code runs fine.

Comment: I'll need to see more of the code changes you've made. But one thought I have is that you probably should break up each of the pieces of this code and understand what that section is doing. Calling print(movies) inside your handler for movies doesn't look right to me.

Comment: So, I only have these 3 files on my project: The connect with the OMDB API: https://pastebin.com/iiKpBzmX The Movie classes and functions: https://pastebin.com/SDSuTNHp And I was doing this print on my AppDelegate: https://pastebin.com/9qZSGx8A

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not going to be able to look at external links. Feel free to edit your code in the question and maybe others can help you with that issue too! Unless I can see the changes you made though I can't help.

Comment: Oh, sorry. But the only change I did was call the function MovieDAO.getMovies on my App Delegate. I was trying this only to see if my function is right and return the array of movies. But my main goal is: I have a table view with a search bar. So the user enter the imdbTitle on this search bar and my table view would show the return of this function. Is there any other way that I can do that? I mean, see if this function getMovies is returning the given response according to the JSON the API gives me.

Comment: Your completion handler should be passed the array of movies you create in the completion handler for search movies